# Will there be a problem if I don't add Python to environment variables? I have installed Python and worked on Pycharm and haven't had any problems

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables

I am working on Python 3.9 with Pycharm and it has worked fine so far. Anytime I need to check something from the command prompt I write 'py [rest of the command]' and it does the work. I am trying to install jupyter now, and will be learning Machine Learning in future. Will this cause any problems?

Comment: No problems. But the question is too broad.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any issues, as python should be already set inside your environment variable, due to the fact that you are able to run python codes with the **py** command, I am assuming running python programs is what you mean by 'does the work'.
Jupyter can be downloaded with two methods, one with the anaconda distribution and other with pip, a python package manager. I would recommend the anaconda distribution because even though it may be a little big in size, it does contain all the other essentials required for machine learning.